# iOS share extension NSUserDefaults issue with stored auth token

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I use RestKit as a library that handle all my request. So I use base authorization and keep my token in user default.

[Here is a good example](http://tapadoo.com/2014/sharing-nsuserdefaults-between-your-app-and-a-today-extension-on-ios-8/) how to get data from app NSUserDefault and use it in my share extension.

So I made this:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.com.myapp"];
NSString *token = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"kUserToken"];
```

But token is `nil` But when I check the same in app it return for me a string.

Also I noticed that I have this error (not sure if it causes error with user defaults):

```
Add the “App Groups” entitlement to your App ID
```

[image]

Comment: Just turn on app groups in your settings of the target (where you turn on stuff like iCloud, Game Center, gps capabilities ect)

Comment: it turned on) but it has that issue